# How do I make multiple JButtons that work individually through instantiating the class?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, textfield

I am just a beginner in java programming, and I got confused in class. Our assignment was to make 3 jButtons, and when you click on them, a gif appears. Our teacher said that we have to show the instantiation of 3 objects, each one controlling one button. Please help me; I am so confused!

This is part of my code (the image Icon part)

```
public void addButtonsToContentPanel() {
    ImageIcon frog    = new ImageIcon("frog.gif");
    ImageIcon buffalo = new ImageIcon("buffalo.gif");

    fancyButton1      = new JButton("Fancy Button", frog);
    fancyButton1.setRolloverIcon(buffalo);


    p.add(fancyButton1);
    fancyButton1.addActionListener(this);
}
```

^^ how do I make the code above so that `fancyButton1` is linked with the instantiation of a class? Sorry If what I'm saying doesn't make sense; I wasn't sure how to word it.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, and yes I do. I just edited my question.

Comment: Sounds like they want a class which creates the a button and manages it

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Sorry, I'm not very good at the programming language ):

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what you by "we have to show the instantiation of 3 objects, each one controlling one button"?

Comment: Initially I made a program called Cyberpet with the instantiations of Cyberpet pet1 = new Cyberpet, Cyberpet pet2 = new Cyberpet2, etc. In this new program, I have to implement the original program so that each distinctive pet gets its own button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fancyButton1 = new ImageButton()
```

By calling `new ImageButton()`, you are instantiating a new object of the class `ImageButton`.

I am unsure quite what you are being asked to do. The following is code which instantiates three buttons:

```
ImageButton fancyButton1 = new ImageButton()
ImageButton fancyButton2 = new ImageButton()
ImageButton fancyButton3 = new ImageButton()
```

The other thing that you may be being asked to do, is to define the Cyberpet class so that it can create its own JButton, something along the following lines:

```
class CyberPet {

    private String name;
    private ImageIcon imgIcon;
    private ImageIcon rolloverImgIcon;

    // Initialiser
    Cyberpet(String name, String pathToImgIcon, String pathToRolloverImgIcon) {
       this.name = name;
       this.imgIcon = new ImageIcon(pathToImgIcon);
       this.rolloverImgIcon = new ImageIcon(pathToRolloverImgIcon);
    }

    public JButton createButton() {
        JButton btn = new JButton(this.name, this.imgIcon);
        btn.setRolloverIcon(this.rolloverImgIcon);
    }
}
```

```
public void addButtonsToContentPanel() {
    Cyberpet frog = new Cyberpet("frog.gif", "buffalo.gif");
    fancyButton1 = frog.createButton();
    fancyButton1.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Hope this helps. If I have misinterpreted the question then please let me know and I will try to provide a better answer.